# How to get branch.io universal links working when another app opens a Safari View Controller?

Tags: ios, branch.io, ios-universal-links, sfsafariviewcontroller

When I open a branch generated link through a third-party app, it opens in a Safari View Controller and won't open my app directly when it is already installed on my phone. Whereas clicking on the link through another app that doesn't open links in Safari View Controller results in opening the app directly as expected. Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has not yet enabled Universal Linking behavior in `SFSafariViewController`, so this is unfortunately the expected behavior. Branch is maintaining [a list of apps that support Universal Links](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links), which you might find useful.

As a workaround, you could consider using Branch's [Deepviews](https://dev.branch.io/features/deepviews/overview/) feature to avoid sending these users directly to the App Store.